# Centralize floated items in a div container

Tags: css, css-float, centering

**First of all this question is not duplicated, Please do not mark it as duplicated till you understand the question**

I have a floated items inside a container div which need to be Centralized.
This is how the items look when applying `float: left`

[image: Floated Items]

most people agree that applying `display:inline-block` for the items and `text-align: center` for the container will do the job. but look at the result. :(
[image: Inline-block Items]

my problem is with the last row of the items, it should be floated to the left.
I need to a solution that combines the advantage of **floating** and the **centralizing** of inline-block in the same time, is this possible?

```css
 .post-item {   
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e9eaed;
    border: 1px solid #ff917b;
 }
 .grid-view{  
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
 margin: auto;
 }
 .list-container{
    float: left;
    background-color: #444444;
    padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <div class="grid-view">
    <div class="post-item">
    </div>
    <div class="post-item">
    </div>
    <div class="post-item">
    </div>
    <div class="post-item">
    </div>
    <div class="post-item">
    </div>
    <div class="post-item">
    </div>
    <div class="post-item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or use the snippet to replicate the issue.

Comment: @SleekGeek Here is a code snippet

Comment: WIll it always be 7 items?

Comment: Is this responsive? and fixed items? from my understanding you want to make all boxes centre align and last row item should be left align? am i right?

Comment: it is responsive but the item's dimension is fixed, I want it to be floated but the container is in the center @shanidkv

Answer (score 0):

I assume `.list-container` is the container for all the images and that you want the images as a group to be centered, but that each individual image must `float : left`?

If so, just remove `float : left` from `.list-container` and have some arrangement of the following:

```
.list-container{
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
   width: auto;
}
```

Those three are necessary to center the container responsively. Leaving individual images with `float : left` should be fine.

Comment: the container is `.grid-view`, and It didn't work, it still looks like first image in the question.

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dokse36n/) and converted your divs into ul and li tags. It seems to do the trick although there's some weird padding on the ul.

Comment: no centralizing is applied, same result with the first image